# Find out missing alternate number

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I data like below , how to find out missing event between records. 
if you see below data on up event is missing (Record4)

```
Datetime,            Event_Type
2019-01-01 00:15:00, Down - Record1
2019-01-01 08:00:00, Up  - Record2
2019-01-01 12:15:00, Down - Record3
2019-01-02 08:00:00, Down - Record5
2019-01-02 13:00:00, Up   - Record6
```

My results should show the exceptions records which are missing consecutive events

Comment: It is not clear what is record1 record2 etc - is it part of type or ids or what?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You should include the results  you want in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if datetime value are unique something like this should work

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN t.event_type = 'DOWN' THEN 'UP'
    ELSE 'DOWN'
  END as missing,
  prev_ids.line_number
FROM my_table t
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 
    t.datetime, 
    MAX(t2.datetime) as previous_datetime, 
    COUNT(t2.datetime) + 1 as line_number
  FROM my_table t LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t.datetime > t2.datetime
  GROUP BY t.datetime
) prev_ids ON t.datetime = prev_ids.datetime
INNER JOIN my_table as prev 
  ON prev.datetime = prev_ids.previous_datetime
WHERE prev.event_type = t.event_type
```

prev_ids - we get previous datetime for each record and count previous records to get the line number

and then just check if record's event_type is equal to previous event_type then here is missing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, changed IF statement to CASE WHEN, so it should fit every DB now

Answer (score 0):

My best interpretation is that you want "up"s and "down"s interleaved.  If so you can get the missing rows using `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when event_type = 'UP' then 'DOWN' else 'UP' 
        end) as missing_event_type
from (select t.*,
             lag(event_type) over (order by datetime) as prev_event_type
      from t
     ) t
where prev_event_type <> event_type;
```